# Is it possible to remove the mesh but keep the outline of this pgf plot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \begin{axis}[domain=-1:1, y domain=-1:1, scale=1/2, hide axis]
    \addplot3[
    , surf
    , samples=20
    , thick
    , color=blue!40!white
    , faceted color=blue!70!black
    , fill opacity=0.60
    ]
    {x^2-y^2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which produces the following output:

[image]

I'd like to remove the "mesh" from this figure, but keep the "outline". Is this possible?

Reducing the number of samples doesn't really help. For `samples=5` we have:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? (I am really asking because I am not sure if you mean this with outline.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \begin{axis}[domain=-1:1, y domain=-1:1, scale=1/2, hide axis]
    \addplot3[point meta=1,
    z buffer=sort,
    surf,
    shader=interp,
    samples=20,
    opacity=0.30
    ]
    {x^2-y^2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can get the outline with a trick: use `point meta` to distinguish points inside and at the boundary. The width of the boundary is inversely proportional to the number of samples, so if you want it relatively small, you may want to use `lualatex` to speed the compilation with many samples.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \begin{axis}[domain=-1:1, y domain=-1:1, scale=1/2, hide axis,
    colormap={blueblack}{color=(black) color=(blue!30)}]
    \addplot3[point meta={1-ifthenelse(abs(x)==1,1,ifthenelse(abs(y)==1,1,0))},
    z buffer=sort,
    surf,
    shader=interp,
    samples=50,
    ]
    {x^2-y^2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With opacity:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \begin{axis}[domain=-1:1, y domain=-1:1, scale=1/2, hide axis,
    colormap={blueblack}{color=(black) color=(blue!30)}]
    \addplot3[point meta={1-ifthenelse(abs(x)==1,1,ifthenelse(abs(y)==1,1,0))},
    z buffer=sort,
    surf,opacity=0,
    samples=50,fill opacity=0.5
    ]
    {x^2-y^2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: By "outline" I mean "the outer edge part of the mesh" (like what one gets with the "filldraw" command in tikz). This is close, but it's missing the outer edge.

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick This is somewhat tricky and the perhaps best way might be to use `point meta`.Other ways are drawing this in two stretches and adding the boundary with a parametric plot (thus arriving at four `\addplot` commands). I added an example for the first method.

Comment: It's interesting the the opacity appears to be lost. Is there a way to recover the opacity?

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick Sure. I added one possible way.